# общая сессия для серверов node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Добрый день.
Есть 2 домена(2 проекта).
Один выполняет функцию авторизации, второй рабочий сайт.
Мои шаги:
1. Авторизации на домене auth.domain.ru
2. Использование домена domain.ru
3. Каждая последующая загрузка любой страницы domain.ru замедляет работу базы данных с таблицей session так, что загрузка страницы становится просто невозможной.

Т.е. я авторизованным открываю сайт domain.ru. Всё нормально. Перезагружаю, перезагружаю, перезагружаю. Загружается уже медленнее. Если перезагрузить еще раз 10, то загрузка уже не выполняется.

И просмотр данных таблицы session тоже становится печален. Окно зависает, потом все-таки прогружается, но не показывает данных столбца с типом jsonb.
База данных postgresql.

После долгого ожидания загрузки страницы, загрузка останавливается и node.js приложение выдает ошибку

> FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - process out of memory

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как решить проблему.

Код сессии:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(session({
store: new pgSession({
    pg : pg,                                  // Use global pg-module
    conString : 'http://postgres:mydatabase@127.0.0.1:5432/data', // Connect using something else than default DATABASE_URL env variable
    tableName : 'session'               // Use another table-name than the default "session" one
}),
secret: 'mysecret',
cookie: {
    maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
    domain: 'domain.ru'
},
resave: false,
saveUninitialized: true,
secure: true
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(cookieParser());
```

Comment: Так вы посмотрели кто съел всю память?

Comment: В Node.js утечка памяти из-за авторизации. 
Довел до момента, когда приложение использует 700 МБ оперативы, и скачет-прыгает с 700 до 1500 мб.

Т.е. проблема в строке "domain: 'domain.ru'".
Даже не знаю что и делать-то.

Comment: Заменил PostgreSql на MongoDB - та же беда.

Comment: Используя MongoDB выдало ошибку:
"RangeError: attempt to write outside buffer bounds"

Т.е. он записывает данные в бд сессии. Но зачем это делается и как вообще? Ведь сервер должен только получать данные из сессии. Странно...

Comment: Из-за этого еще и MongoDB не запускается теперь, выдает:
"***aborting after fassert() failure", при ошибке "Fatal Assertion 34433"
И это исправляется только удалением бд(

Comment: Ну так выясните почему у вас каждый раз новая сессия создаётся.

Comment: Не вышло выяснить почему сессия записывается в бд постоянно, но ошибка была в том, что часть данных записывалась в виде строки JSON, а другая в объекте. Из-за этого к кавычкам постоянно добавлялись слэши "//", и тем самым увеличивался размер данных более 16 МБ